# Vazamento de memória com Scala e processos (memory leak)

Tags: java, memória, scala

Tenho um sistema razoavelmente complexo em Scala, com várias threads e chamadas de sistema simultâneas. Esse sistema está com algum problema, pois memória ocupada cresce ao longo do tempo.

Pela imagem abaixo, vê-se a ocupação de memória da máquina ao longo de um dia. Quando chega no limite, o processo cai e eu coloquei um watch-dog para levanta-lo de novo. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu rodo periodicamente o comando

```
jcmd <pid> GC.run
```

E isso faz com que a memória não cresça tão rapidamente, mas ainda assim o problema persista.

Fiz uma análise com o jvisualvm, comparando o heap em 2 momentos distintos, com 40 minutos de diferença. A imagem abaixo mostra um comparativo entre o heap no tempo 1 com o heap no tempo 0. Note que há um aumento considerável de instâncias de algumas classes, como `ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry`, `SNode`, `WeakReference`, `char[]` e `String` e várias classes do pacote `scala.collection.concurrent`.

O que pode estar causando o meu memory leak?

[image: Objetos vazando memória]

**Edit 1**:
Investigando pelo JVisualVM, notei que os objetos da classe CNode e INode estão em TriedMap, que por sua vez são instanciados na classe sbt.TrapExit$App. Veja a hierarquia de objetos na figura:

[image: hierarquia de objetos]

[Post em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834981/memory-leak-in-scala-and-processes)

Comment: Pode ser que está havendo o memory leak por causa dos java weak references no SNode. Alguma(s) parte do código podem estar causando isto. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.ref.WeakReference

Comment: Amigo, de uma olhada nesse [tutorial](http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/memory_leak_em_java.php#.VBg8A9_0_0o). Depois de uma analizada no seu código novamente. :)

Comment: Olhei o artigo, Fabio, mas não ajuda muito... eu não encontro no meu código nenhum ponto onde eu esteja armazenando objetos que não perdem referências, pelos menos não que eu tenha identificado...

Answer (score 4):

Esses objetos são todos parte do `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap`. Como, pelo que você indicou, quem usa isso é o SBT, minha sugestão é que você deixe de usar o SBT para iniciar sua aplicação.

Use um plugin do SBT como o sbt-one-jar, sbt-assembly ou sbt-proguard que gere um JAR contendo todas as dependências, de forma que você possa iniciar sua aplicação com `java -jar sua-aplicacao.jar`.

Comment: Não entendi... Que mapas concorrentes? Eu não uso mapas concorrentes no meu código. E como verificar o número de elementos em um mapa concorrente?

Comment: @DanielCukier Se voce não usa, alguma biblioteca que você está usando usa. Aí, realmente, não tenho como recomendar muita coisa, pois quem está consumindo memória é essa biblioteca -- ou seja lá o que estiver usando mapa concorrente.

Comment: dê uma olhada na nova figura

Comment: @DanielCukier Você está executando a aplicação com o SBT? Por acaso é uma aplicação Play, ou tem alguma outra razão para você usar o SBT?

Comment: Não é Play, mas executo usando sbt sim. Uso por praticidade... sbt run

Comment: @DanielCukier Ok, alterei minha resposta baseado nisso.